# Cannot convert lambda expression to type delegate because delegate is not a type

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem that I can't seem to figure out, although its kind of a standard question here on StackOverflow.

```
base.Invoke(() => prgWork.Value = 100);
```

What am I doing wrong?
When I compile it I get the error message:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type delegate because delegate is not a type

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
base.Invoke((Action)(() => { prgWork.Value = 100; }));
```

Comment: this seems mostly like a comment.Please check [how to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). 
Add more details to justify your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Invoke` takes a `Delegate`, rather than a typed `Delegate` to make the method as generic as possible. The problem is that type `Delegate` is an abstract type, and in order for the compiler to infer the number and Types of arguments or the return type of your lambda, you must provide a "concrete" `Delegate` type. A common solution to this is to wrap your lambda in an `Action` delegate, as `Action` derives from `Delegate`. In fact, you can pass any type that inherits from `Delegate`, directly or indirectly, including custom delegates you define in your project.

Try something like this:

```
base.Invoke(new Action(() => { prgWork.Value = 100; }));
```

If you find yourself using `Invoke` often, I would suggest creating an extension method such as this:

```
public static void Invoke(this Control control, Action action)
{
    control.Invoke(action);
}
```

Or with C#6 syntax

```
public static void Invoke(this Control control, Action action) => control?.Invoke(action);
```

And now you will be able to use it like this:

```
someControl.Invoke(() => { prgWork.Value = 100; });
```

Here the compiler will create a `new Action` object for you, cleaning up your code. This also sheds some light on why your attempt did not work. You were basically asking the compiler to create an instance of the abstract class `Delegate`.